# How to calculte water T flowin in a insulated pipe

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer

folllowing this subject, [Calculating the temperature of the lagging around an insulated pipe](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/calculating-the-temperature-of-the-lagging-around-an-insulated-pipe/52840?noredirect=1#comment99634_52840)

how can i calculate **the temperature of the water at the end of the pipe**, for L=100m,  given T ambient, thermal conductivity of 0.05 W/m·K and a thermal conductance of 10 W/m2·K

Comment: What have you considered so far? This is not a free homework completion service.

Comment: you are missing flow rate and inlet water temp.

Comment: To add to tigerguy's comment, other useful comments is tube diameter (to estimate Reynolds number) and also any information regarding the roughness inside the tube.